# Unable to cast object of type... converting a label into a double variable

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-conversion, typeconverter

hi in this code im trying to convert a double from a label into the variable but im coming up with the exception

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'."

on the `"convert.toDouble(lblPricekey);"` area and I'm not sure why.

```
  private void btnAddtoTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double numPadTotal;
        numPadTotal = Convert.ToDouble(lblPricekey.Text);

        double finalTotal = total + numPadTotal;
        txtTotal.Text = finalTotal.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you need to first retrieve the value of the label, then cast that value to a double.

Comment: `"convert.toDouble(lblPricekey);"` you can't convert the label Object to a double you need to `convert.toDouble(lblPricekey.Text);` for this to work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting `Label` to `double`. You should convert `Label.Text`.

```
numPadTotal = Convert.ToDouble(lblPricekey.Text);
```

Comment: ahh totaly forgot to add the .Text thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
private void btnAddtoTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double numPadTotal = Convert.ToDouble(lblPricekey.Text);

    double finalTotal = total + numPadTotal;
    txtTotal.Text = finalTotal.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`lblPricekey` is a type of `label`. You can't convert it to `double`. Use `Text` property for converting. It represents `string`. Look at from *[`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text.aspx)*.

> Gets or sets the text content of the Label control.

Try like this;

```
numPadTotal = Convert.ToDouble(lblPricekey.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to this is use the [TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx)

```
            double numPadTotal;
            var IsDouble = double.TryParse(lblPricekey.Text, out numPadTotal);
            if (IsDouble)
            {
                double finalTotal = total + numPadTotal;
                txtTotal.Text = finalTotal.ToString();
            }
```